# download from blob when given its uri fails in c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to download a file from Azure blob and save it locally, but it seems to fail.
Here's the relevant code:

```
    var blobClientCode = client.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    string codeUri = "https://???.blob.core.windows.net/...../mycode.exe";
    using (var codeContent = File.OpenWrite("C:\\code.exe")) {
        blobClientCode.GetBlockBlobReference(codeUri).DownloadToStream(codeContent);
    }
```

I get an error in which the container doens't exist. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting a reference to the container first then defining the CloudBlockBlob from this using just the relative path.

This is the code that works for me:

```
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("myContainerName");

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("/subfolder/filename.exe");
using (fileStream == System.IO.File.OpenWrite("C:\code.exe")) {
    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: Yes I have. that container has public access

Comment: I've revised my answer, with some alternative code you can try.

Comment: In my program I get the full URI as a variable, do you suggest just to parse it like you did? I also get UnauthorizedAccessException, might it be because the local file doesn't exist? How do I create a new file locally?

Comment: Your application is trying to write to the C Drive root which will likely cause a permissions problem, unless you have explicitly granted write permissions. Try writing to the application root first to eliminate this error.. you can use server.mappath ("\code exe")