# Fail to download a file programmatically (C#)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I write a c# program connected to an Azure Storage Account.

Given a blob URI, I need to download the file to a local file and execute it.

Here's my piece of code:

```
var blobClientCode = client.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlockBlob codeBlob = blobClientCode.GetBlockBlobReference(codeUri);
File.Create("C:\\code.exe");
using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite("C:\\code.exe")) {
     codeBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
}

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\mycode.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = dataUri;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

The problem is that I keep getting UnauthorizedAccess Exception.

- When I try to download the file manually from the browser (copy & paste the URI) I succeed.
- The container is a public one.
- I also tried to use WebClient.DownloadFile(), and got WebException.

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: is the URI starting with http or https??..If it starts with https..is the certificate verified ?

Comment: @RohitAgrawal it's starts with https. But I didn't understand the question...how do I verify it?

Comment: when you are copy pasting it in the browser is it opening directly or opening with a warning that the certificate is not verified..do u still want to continue ?

Comment: opens directly...it directly starts downloading the file

Comment: In which line does the exception occur? Any inner exceptions?

Comment: Not that I know of...

Comment: @user1067083 You already asked the same question here just yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992989/download-from-blob-when-given-its-uri-fails-in-c-sharp/15993273#15993273

Comment: @QF_Developer it's not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so thanks to all of you I've finally reached into a solution:

What I've finally done was defining a local storage in the service definition of the roles, like this:

```
<LocalResources>
<LocalStorage name="myLocalStorage" sizeInMB="10" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
</LocalResources>
```

And then just used this local storage to download the file from the blob and execute it:

```
LocalResource localResource = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("myLocalStorage");
string PathToFile = Path.Combine(localResource.RootPath, "mycode.exe");
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
webclient.DownloadFile(codeUri, PathToFile);

Process p = new Process(); //...
```

Thanks again to all of you

Answer (score 1):

Try including the below mention code snippet before calling webclient.DownloadFile. Hope it should work..

```
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });

 WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
webclient.DownloadFile(new Uri(URIPath), LocalPath);
```

Note : if you are accessing internet using proxy you might need to set the proxy setting

```
WebProxy ProxyObject = ProxySetting;
webclient.Proxy = ProxySetting
```

;

This basically navigates the page irrespective whether the certificate is verified or not.

Comment: @user1067083 can you Please post the exact error exception which you are getting

Comment: The weird thing is that it works if I run it in the computer with emulator, but I get this error exception only when I run it in the cloud

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're trying to write the file to `C:` drive. In Windows Azure this is not allowed out of the box. Please see this blog post for details: http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2011/06/12/azure-faq-can-i-write-to-the-file-system-on-windows-azure/. As mentioned in the blog post, one option could be to save the blob to local storage and execute from there.

Comment: It worked when I ran that program locally (from my computer). It connected to my Azure storage and ran the entire thing. This error I get is only when the worker role is running in cloud

Comment: This may be because when we run stuff in local emulator, we run the code in elevated privilege mode (remember you would run Visual Studio as Administrator) which gives permission to write to C:\. Same is not true when code is running in the cloud.

Comment: So what should I do? I haven't understand a thing from you link, and I'm not completely familiar with c# yet

Comment: Take a look at this link for some help on using local resources: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758708.aspx. Essentially, you would configure local resource in your configuration file and instead of using "C:\", you would be using your local resource's root directory. HTH.

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind sharing for the rest of us how did you get it working. It would be really beneficial.

Comment: Sure... I'll write my own answer below